# sharepoint designer saves the changes but it does not affect

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I add a tag to my page source in share point designer to use in my javascript,
 and then save it. but when I refresh my page, it shows me that its not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that version control isn't acting on that resource? You should check in a major version to publish it.

Right click on the page and then there is an option to check in a major version (see below screenshots).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This "What type of version do you want to check in" section is not shown on my dialog box when I try to do check in. Any ideas why is that?